# SVG and Google Fonts

Tags: fonts, svg

I would like to use SVG files for some tables on a website, the code weighs in at a lightweight 35Kb and, of course, it's scalable.

I am using `<object>` as the embedding method (basically after trying and failing with `<img>`.

Unfortunately the only way I can get the use of site fonts is by putting in a call to google fonts within the SVG file itself.

```
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans');
</style>
```

which, instinctively seems like bad practice.

Is it bad practice? Is there a better way to access the site fonts?

Comment: I'm confused why you're not using your site CSS style sheet to add the font?

Comment: This Stack Exchange site is primarily for [managing websites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), questions related to [coding](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are best asked over at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). It seems like you might want to clarify it a bit first prior to posting there however (based on the comments here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for svg you should use the html Tag:

```
 <svg> in the format : <svg type="text/svg" src="/FileSrc.svg"></svg>
```

Not image or object. 
& Google fonts are generally included in the head section of the html and then referenced through font-family in your Css..

When you say tables Are you reffering to an svg font table?
The question is not very clear as to what your asking, please re-edit and and some more information...

Css @imports whould be less secure than a html call with an intergrity attribute, but its still unclear what your saying...

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity. The table was an display table (infographic), as it was a one-off the time to code as HTML/CSS meant it was better inserted as an image and SVG seemed a better idea than a PNG but, as you point out, SVG is code not an image. I hope this clarifies but I will leave it there as the question is seen as inappropriate for this forum. Thanks for your help.